# Are these two sets the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a set of real numbers $S$ and I want a set with the negative of all the elements in $S$. Would signifying that $-s \in \mathbb{R}$ have any effect on changing the second set as different from the first?

are these two sets the same?:

$-S=\{-s:s \in S\}$ and

$-S=\{-s \in \mathbb{R}:s \in S\}$

Comment: depends if S is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If so then yes.

Comment: You mean perhaps $\{s\in{\mathbb R}, -s\in S\}$ for the second set?

Comment: @Gribouillis no I meant what I wrote, I took a test today where I used the second set to show that the supremum for the set $S$ would be the infimum of the set $-S$ since the set $S$ was bounded above. I couldn't remember the correct way to denote $-S$ so I wrote the second one only to look in the book and see it was proved using the first one. I want to know if my proof remains correct with the notation $-S=\{-s \in \mathbb{R} :s \in S\}$ What do you think?Is it still correct?

Comment: I think the second notation is unconventional. I think you are mixing up two notations, the first one and the one I wrote above.

Comment: Yes it is the 'set builder notation'. The first notation that you wrote could be described as the 'direct image notation'. You define a set by taking the image of S by the mapping $s\mapsto -s$. Edit: by the way it is 'Take all elements in ${\mathbb R}$ such that ...'

Comment: @Gribouillis I am sorry to bother you but, can you please just answer this question. Does the second set I wrote above not have the same elements as the first set and the set you wrote above? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first is more the "normal", clearer, notation, but both would denote the same set.